# How to register a single property (not a property group) in blender 2.8? (Python API)

Tags: properties

## How to register a single property (not a property group) in blender 2.8?

### My attempt

This is what I am doing at the moment inside my addon `__init__.py`:

```
# ...
bpy.types.Material.myprop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProp)
# ...
```

with `MyProp` class:

```
class MyProp(bpy.types.Property):
    name: "Some name"
    description: "Some description"
```

The idea is so I can see access this property through:

```
bpy.data.materials['Material'].myprop
```

Here's the error I am getting when loading the add-on:

```
bpy.types.Material.myprop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Myprop)
ValueError: bpy_struct "Material" registration error: myprop could not register
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silly me... This is what I was looking for:

```
bpy.types.Material.myprop = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="myprop")
```

Reference:

[Assigning property to existing class](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.props.html)